# java.util.Properties: How do I retrieve values from Properties in spring config xml

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

I have a java.util.Properties object which has few key value pairs in it. I am trying to use this Property object in the spring configuration file i.e. define the key in the spring config and during runtime, it should get the value from the properties object.

For ex:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.sample.Test">
    <constructor-arg value="${PROPERTY_KEY} />
</bean>
```

Now during the runtime, the constructor should get the value that is present in the Property object.

Is there a way to get this done ?

Note: I do not want to use config.properties here. Looking to use java.util.Properties

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: `<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="your-properties-bean-id" />`. Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Denium. I will try this out. But not sure how as I dont have the property bean id in the xml and I cannot create one as well.

Comment: Then where do you have that properties object? And why wouldn't you be able to create it in XML? Can you add more information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:placeholder.properties"/>
```

or

```
<bean id="properties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location" value="classpath:<file-name>.properties" />

</bean>
```

Comment: He explicitly states he doesn't want to use a file.

Comment: Hi, as Denium rightly says I do not want to use any property file to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create bean to access your property file, like below

```
<bean id="appProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
            <list>
          <value>classpath*:localhost-mysql.properties</value>
          <value>classpath*:mail-server.properties</value>
          </list>
    </property>     
</bean>
<bean id="placeholderConfig"    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="appProperties" />
</bean>
```

Next you can access Key-Value pair from your property files, like below

```
<bean id="mailServerSettings" class="com.ratormonitor.app.context.EmailSettings">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.server.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mail.server.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mail.server.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.server.password}" />
    <property name="requestContextPath" value="${request.context.path}" />
</bean>
```

Hope this code will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Senthil, Thanks for the answer, however as mentioned in the question, I don't want to use any property file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Spring Expression Language (SpEL) to get a java object value in spring configuration xml file.

An example :

```
<property name="misfireInstruction"
                          value="#{T(org.quartz.CronTrigger).MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I did:

As I said I had a java.util.Properties object. I then created a CustomProperty class which extended PropertySource>

```
public class CustomPropertySource extends PropertySource<Map<String, Object>>
```

Then in my main class I did the following:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {springConfigLocation, false);
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources.addlast(new CustomPropertySource("custom", propertiesObject));
conext.refresh();
```

And then in the spring config file, I had to add this:

```
<context: property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

So in this way, I could fetch values for the keys defined in the spring config file, just like how we get the values from property files.

Thanks,
Rahul